# Construct a sample space $\Omega$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Construct a sample space $\Omega$ and events $A_1,\ldots, A_n$ ($n\ge2$) such that $\operatorname{Pr}(A_i) = \frac12$ ($1 \le i \le n$), every $n-1$ of the $A_i$ are independent, but the $n$ events are not independent.

Please help, I stuck for hours on this one.

Comment: I have very little idea to begin with. I have thought this sample space should have Pr (A1) = ... = Pr(An-1) = 1/2 , and A1...An-1 are independent events. Let An = A1 U A2 U ....An-1, thus An are not independent.

Comment: Can you come up with one for $n=3$ in which each outcome (element of $\Omega$) has the same probability?

Comment: How about choosing exactly one ball from a box with 3 balls (red , green, blue) ?

Comment: Are you required to come up with a collection of $A_i$ for each integer $n \geq 3$, or just one example for $n=3$ suffices? If the latter, then consider dfeuer's hint with $A_1$ and $A_2$ being independent events of probability $\frac 12$ each and $A_3$ also an event of probability $\frac 12$ and a Boolean function of $A_1$ and $A_2$. Subhint: there are $6$ such Boolean functions and you can easily eliminate $4$ of the choices.

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate, Thanks for help. I am required to find that collection when n>=3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $n-1$ independent symmetric random signs $(X_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n-1}$. These are independent random variables such that $P[X_k=-1]=\frac12$ and $P[X_k=1]=\frac12$ for every $1\leqslant k\leqslant n-1$. Let $X_n=X_1X_2\cdots X_{n-1}$, so that $X_n$ is also a symmetric random sign. Then a solution to your problem is to define, for every $1\leqslant k\leqslant n$, $A_k=[X_k=1]$. This works for every $n\geqslant2$ (*can you show it does?*).

The events $(A_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}$ are not independent since $A_1\cap A_2\cap\cdots\cap A_n=A_1\cap A_2\cap\cdots\cap A_{n-1}$ hence $P[A_1\cap A_2\cap\cdots\cap A_n]=\left(\frac12\right)^{n-1}$ while $P[A_k]=\frac12$ for every $1\leqslant k\leqslant n$ hence $P[A_1]P[A_2]\cdots P[A_n]=\left(\frac12\right)^{n}$.

About the sample space: I strongly advise to leave $\Omega$ unspecified, as is done above. However, if your teacher insists (for which pedagogical reasons I would *love* to know), a solution is to consider the discrete hypercube $\Omega=\{0,1\}^{n-1}$ endowed with the sigma-algebra $2^\Omega$ and the uniform probability $P$, and to define $A_n=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid\omega_1+\omega_2+\cdots+\omega_{n-1}\ \text{even}\}$ and $A_k=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid\omega_k=1\}$ for every $1\leqslant k\leqslant n-1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You have cleared my mind.

Comment: There is a similar construction on page 11 of Nelson's radical probability theory, according to who, "This is in principle on which a good detective story is based."